# wifi router linux based - customizable

Tags: linux, router, wireless-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a customizable Linux based WiFi router](https://superuser.com/questions/198716/looking-for-a-customizable-linux-based-wifi-router)

Hi,
I m looking for a wifi router (Internet gateway)
currently My ISP provided me a wired router

It should be customizable (able to load linux kernel, rootfs ) and should be linux based one.
Basically I want to learn networking as well hack the kernel too.

Please suggest.

Thanks
Kmr

Comment: This product: http://www.ubnt.com/rspro from some place like http://store.netgate.com/RSPRO-RouterStationPro-Indoor-Kit-v20-P1652C87.aspx#  Or hack a Linksys with DD-WRT: http://www.dd-wrt.com/

Comment: Just recently tested NETGEAR WNR3500L. Works nice with DD-WRT and other alternative firmwares. Check out http://www.myopenrouter.com/

Answer (score 0):

A popular choice is routers that are compatible with [HyperWRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperWRT)-based firmware, such as [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/), [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/) and [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato). These firmware were originally designed for the [Linksys WRT54G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series) routers (which ran a Linux firmware in the first place), but have since been ported to other brands (check the respective firmware pages for compatibility lists). If you go with Linksys, note that not all WRT54G series models support third-party Linux-based firmwares.

A router is not what I'd use to learn kernel hacking, even networking. You'll get more mileage out of a bunch of virtual machines. You can have many of those at no extra cost, and it's less annoying when you have to reboot them.

Comment: One note: the linux compatible version called WRT54GL. The ending 'L' indicates that.

Comment: @cstamas: It's a little more complicated than that: all L models ship with Linux, but many non-L models also ship with or can run Linux (including the *older* just-WRT54G models).

Comment: true, but if the asker wants a new one wrt54gl is the true bet (easier than checking serial numbers and hw revisions). The full list is here btw. http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start (well for openwrt).